# When did Picard lose his hair?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, jean-luc-picard, star-trek-nemesis

In the movie *Star Trek:Nemesis*, Picard looks at an image of himself in Starfleet academy, and it seems he was already completely bald even then. Yet, in the TNG episode 'Tapestry', it flashes back to Picard as an ensign (**after** graduating from the academy, according to [memory-alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jean-Luc_Picard)) with a full head of hair. Did the people behind Nemesis not watch this well-known episode of TNG?

Comment: I'm... not really sure what kind of answer you're looking for here.  Do you want us to tell you which one is wrong?  Because I'm not really sure how to figure that.

Comment: Perhaps he grew it back and then changed his mind.

Comment: Maybe he misheard the opening sequence and thought that he had to "***baldly go*** *where no man had gone before*". By the time he'd realised his mistake, it was too late and he'd already shaved it.

Comment: Wasn't it in X-Men: Apocalypse?

Comment: Picard never had hair. Any of his baby photos will prove it.

Answer (score 9):

Picard appears to have lost his hair during his time at Starfleet Academy (per the image shown in [Nemesis](https://www.yourprops.com/movieprops/default/yp_4fea827244bf89.05372355/Star-Trek-Nemesis-Young-Picard-Prop-Photo-1.jpg)). There are a few clues that he may have taken some sort of temporary cure (or simply worn [a wig](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_XNPD380IpBQ/TISHvDuRU6I/AAAAAAAALhE/RyQDTLyrkE4/s1600/P311_1.jpg)), based on his appearance in TNG: Tapestry, TNG: Violations and Boothy's reaction in [TNG: The First Duty](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/219.txt)

> **PICARD:** (prompting) *Jean-Luc Picard... class of twenty-seven.*
>
> **BOOTHBY:** *I know that. What happened to your hair?*

[image]

---

That being said, the sequence in [TNG: Violations](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Violations_(episode)) was based on Beverly Crusher's (possibly imperfect) memories of Picard as a younger man. [TNG: Tapestry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tapestry_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)) was potentially a [Q construct](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sherwood_Forest) (as opposed to real time travel). He might have given Picard hair simply to mock him.

Comment: In addition to Valorum's good answer...in TNG: The Inner Light (S5:E25), Picard in his "other life" as Kamen, has a son, Betai, who happens to be played by Daniel Stewart (Sir Patrick's real son). Young Batai, has a full head of hair (or wearing a rug) when his character is around 20 or so: http://i.stack.imgur.com/w13qB.jpg In real life, however, Daniel is bald like his father: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SS4z1.jpg

Comment: I'm not an expert on the stardates/timeline, but is it really plausible that he lost that very full head of hair so quickly? I've known many balding people, and they don't just wake up one morning without their hair. As far as Q making it up to mock Picard - I don't think it's compelling - there's no indication from Picard that that is the case, or that Q changed any other detail. I can't speak to your point about Violations - it's one of the few episodes I never saw. From the image it seems to take place after he left the academy, which strengthens my question.

Comment: @Woody It's completely plausible for Picard to lose hair so quickly, as Patrick Stewart himself says he lost all his hair within a year and was bald by nineteen.  It may have been the writers choosing to reflect his actual life.  http://www.belgraviacentre.com/blog/patrick-stewart-on-parkinson-the-best-interview-about-baldness/

Comment: @Woody Many people who get obvious bald patches or receding hairline decide to just go all the way, and shave it all off — effectively, waking up one morning without their hair.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68116/discussion-on-answer-by-valorum-when-did-picard-lose-his-hair).